# POST request via requests (python) not returning data

Tags: python, post, python-requests, multipartform-data

I have another question about posts. 
This post should be almost identical to one referenced on stack overflow using this question 'Using request.post to post multipart form data via python not working', but for some reason I can't get it to work. The website is http://www.camp.bicnirrh.res.in/predict/. I want to post a file that is already in the FASTA format to this website and select the 'SVM' option using requests in python. This is based on what @NorthCat gave me previously, which worked like a charm:

```
import requests
import urllib
file={'file':(open('Bishop/newdenovo2.txt','r').read())}
url = 'http://www.camp.bicnirrh.res.in/predict/hii.php'
payload = {"algo[]":"svm"}
raw = urllib.urlencode(payload)
response = session.post(url, files=file, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Since it's not working, I assumed the payload was the problem. I've been playing with the payload, but I can't get any of these to work.

```
payload = {'S1':str(data), 'filename':'', 'algo[]':'svm'} # where I tried just reading the file in, called 'data'
payload = {'svm':'svm'} # not actually in the headers, but I tried this too)
payload = {'S1': '', 'algo[]':'svm', 'B1': 'Submit'}
```

None of these payloads resulted in data.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Does replacing `open('Bishop/newdenovo2.txt','r').read()` with `open('Bishop/newdenovo2.txt','r')` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the file post variable name to "userfile", i.e.

```
file={'userfile':(open('Bishop/newdenovo2.txt','r').read())}
```

Note that the `read()` is unnecessary, but it doesn't prevent the file upload succeeding. Here is some code that should work for you:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()
response = session.post('http://www.camp.bicnirrh.res.in/predict/hii.php',
               files={'userfile': ('fasta.txt', open('fasta.txt'), 'text/plain')},
               data={'algo[]':'svm'})
```

`response.text` contains the HTML results, save it to a file and view it in your browser, or parse it with something like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and extract the results.

In the request I've specified a mime type of "text/plain" for the file. This is not necessary, but it serves as documentation and might help the receiving server.

The content of my `fasta.txt` file is:

```
>24.6jsd2.Tut 
GGTGTTGATCATGGCTCAGGACAAACGCTGGCGGCGTGCTTAATACATGCAAGTCGAACGGGCTACCTTCGGGTAGCTAGTGGCGGACGGGTGAGTAACACGTAGGTTTTCTGCCCAATAGTGGGGAATAACAGCTCGAAAGAGTTGCTAATACCGCATAAGCTCTCTTGCGTGGGCAGGAGAGGAAACCCCAGGAGCAATTCTGGGGGCTATAGGAGGAGCCTGCGGCGGATTAGCTAGATGGTGGGGTAAAGGCCTACCATGGCGACGATCCGTAGCTGGTCTGAGAGGACGGCCAGCCACACTGGGACTGAGACACGGCCCAGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAAGGAATATTCCACAATGGCCGAAAGCGTGATGGAGCGAAACCGCGTGCGGGAGGAAGCCTTTCGGGGTGTAAACCGCTTTTAGGGGAGATGAAACGCCACCGTAAGGTGGCTAAGACAGTACCCCCTGAATAAGCATCGGCTAACTACGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGTAGGATGCAAGCGTTGTCCGGATTTACTGGGCGTAAAGCGCGCGCAGGCGGCAGGTTAAGTAAGGTGTGAAATCTCCCTGCTCAACGGGGAGGGTGCACTCCAGACTGACCAGCTAGAGGACGGTAGAGGGTGGTGGAATTGCTGGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATCAGCAGGAACACCCGTGGCGAAGGCGGCCACCTGGGCCGTACCTGACGCTGAGGCGCGAAGGCTAGGGGAGCGAACGGGATTAGATACCCCGGTAGTCCTAGCAGTAAACGATGTCCACTAGGTGTGGGGGGTTGTTGACCCCTTCCGTGCCGAAGCCAACGCATTAAGTGGACCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGTCGCAAGACTAAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGACCCGCACAAGCAGCGGAGCGTGTGGTTTAATTCGATGCGACGCGAAGAACCTTACCTGGGCTTGACATGCTATCGCAACACCCTGAAAGGGGTGCCTCCTTCGGGACGGTAGCACAGATGCTGCATGGCTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCCTGTCCTTAGTTGTATATCTAAGGAGACTGCCGGAGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAGTCAGCATGGCTCTTACGTCCAGGGCTACACATACGCTACAATGGCCGTTACAGTGAGATGCCACACCGCGAGGTGGAGCAGATCTCCAAAGGCGGCCTCAGTTCAGATTGCACTCTGCAACCCGAGTGCATGAAGTCGGAGTTGCTAGTAACCGCGTGTCAGCATAGCGCGGTGAATATGTTCCCGGGTCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACGTCATGGGAGCCGGCAACACTTCGAGTCCGTGAGCTAACCCCCCCTTTCGAGGGTGTGGGAGGCAGCGGCCGAGGGTGGGGCTGGTGACTGGGACGAAGTCGTAACAAGGT
```